# how to link balance to other sheet in excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file with multiple sheets, **for example:**

`Jan18`, `Feb18`, `Mar18`, `Apr18`, `May18`, `Jun18` , `Jul18`

I want to bring forward a cell value to the next sheet.

**For example:**

- I want to bring forward `Jan18` `D32` value to `Feb18` `E32`.
- This is the formula inserted in `Feb18` `E32`: `='JAN18'!D32`
- From here I successfully brought forward the value from `Jan18`, but when I copy paste all of the sheet of `Feb18` to `Mar18`, the value of `E32` in `Mar18` is same with `Jan18` `D32` because the formula use is still `= 'JAN18'!D32`

I want a formula to make it when I copy paste all of the sheet to update it's balance B/F according to it's previous sheet. Is that possible?

Comment: post photo of your workbook and what you want outcome to look like

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. One of the ways to do it is using the "indirect" function and combine it the the month you want the take the balance from. In this case, the previous month. 
Have a look at it here: [excel INDIRECT function](https://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html#RefSheet)